# How do you register a Mount in Lost Ark?

Tags: lost-ark

I use ALT and V to bring up my Mount window. But how do you register your Mount, so that we may left mouse click on the icon to mount and dismount? I have tried to drag to icon onto the potion tab, but it says potions only.

Or can you tell me some other ways to get Mount? Can I buy one of them?

Comment: Plagiarized from https://forums.playlostark.com/t/how-do-you-register-a-mount/124767 with spam link edited in later.  @ShadowTheKidWizard see [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110030/165261)

Comment: @RyanM if done shortly after asking then yeah, justify instant nuke, however more than 6 months passed, and it's a useful question after all, with answer having upvotes. I'd better see spammer nuked but keep the post here.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom five hotkeys can only be used for potions, but the top 5 can be used for mounts after you've registered the mount by Right-Clicking it in your inventory.

For ease of use, I've changed the bind for the final hotkey from <kbd>9</kbd> to Mouse 4, and set the mount to that.

Comment: Worth noting that the bottom row are for 'Battle items' and could be anything from potions, capes or grenades :)

Comment: I would add 1) Mounts can also be favorited in the Alt + V menu for easier access 2) You can get more mounts from Adventure Tomes, Twitch Drops, In game shop, Quests 3) You can only have one type of each battle item in the hotbar (re David's comment)